# Что значит зачёркнутый System? И как это исправить?

Tags: java

[image: Что значит зачёркнутый System? И как это исправить?]

Что значит зачёркнутый System? И как это исправить?

Comment: А у вас среда IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Так IDE отмечает устаревшие методы. Возможно у вас ошибка в импорте.

Comment: Зачеркнутые методы\классы - это обычно deprecated (устаревшие). Те, которые больше не рекомендуется использовать. Но конкретно в вашем случае не очень понятно почему зачеркнут класс System. Он точно не устаревший) Проверте откуда это класс System. Должен быть из пакета java.lang

Comment: Уточните какая система, среда разработки, версия java. Совпадает ли версия jdk c версией виртуальной машины java. Видит ли ваша IDE  jdk?

Comment: Поставьте курсор на зачеркнутый участок и прочтите подсказку.